# iOS 17: Layout Issue with Position Absolute Elements

Tags: css-position, ios17

On iOS 17, I am encountering a layout problem where the `.content` element seems to be covering the `.header` element, resulting in unexpected rendering. This issue is not consistently reproducible across different devices or browsers.

Here's the HTML and CSS structure:

[demo](https://xs9627.github.io/iOS17-position-bug/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            .page {
                position: absolute;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            .container {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            .header {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                background: lightblue;
                height: 50px;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .content {
                height: 2000px;
                background: lightcoral;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header">header</div>
                <div class="content">content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

If remove overflow in `.page`, or make `.content` not scrollable, `.header` shows correct that overlap `.content`

---

Update:

This has been fixed in iOS 17.2. For more information, visit: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737015